# What's wrong in my classpath configuration with java 1.7?

Tags: java, configuration, classpath

I'm trying to run a complied class with the command:`java SocketTest` in current directory.
But something wrong:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:SocketTest(wrong
>   name:socket/SocketTest)...

here is my classpath AND path configration in windows XP:
`JAVA_HOME`:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\
```

classpath:

```
.;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\dt.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar
```

path:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin;C:\Ruby187\bin;H:\Program Files\ARM\ADSv1_2\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\BINN
```

I think the `.;` has been carefully written,so I'm not sure what's wrong with the java command. Someone help,please!

Comment: Show the structure of the class and how you are running the command.

Comment: Probably a package issue. Your classes need to be in directories reflecting the package structure, and you run `java` from whichever directory is the root of that structure. If your class `SocketTest` is in package `socket`, then your file `SocketTest.class` needs to be in a directory `./socket`.

Comment: Your %JAVA_HOME% might not be the problem.  Your %PATH% certainly isn't the problem.  SUGGESTION: debug by trying your "java" command from a command prompt.

Comment: @chrylis your tips work for me,thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message has pointed out you need to put the your class to the corrected package `socket`. So you need to create folder with name `socket` and then put your `SocketTest.class` to this folder and run the following command (under the parent folder of `socket`):

```
java socket.SocketTest
```